# NSDecimalNumber and popping digits off of the end

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I'm not quite sure what to call it, but I have a text field to hold a currency value, so I'm storing that as a NSDecimalNumber. I don't want to use the numbers & symbols keyboard so I'm using a number pad, and inferring the location of a decimal place like ATMs do. It works fine for entering numbers. Type 1234 and it displays $12.34 but now I need to implement back space. So assuming $12.34 is entered hitting back space would show $1.23. I'm not quite sure how to do this with a decimal number. With an int you would just divide by 10 to remove the right most digit, but that obviously doesn't work here. I could do it by some messy converting to int / 10 then back to decimal but that just sounds horrific... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByDividingBy:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber withBehavior:(id < NSDecimalNumberBehaviors >)behavior` on it

Answer (score 0):

How about using stringValue?

1) NSDecimalNumber to String

2) substring last

3) String to NSDecimalNumber

---

Below is an example for Swift 3

```
func popLastNumber(of number: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {

  let stringFromNumber = number.stringValue //NSNumber property

  let lastIndex = stringFromNumber.endIndex
  let targetIndex = stringFromNumber.index(before: lastIndex)
  let removed = stringFromNumber.substring(to: targetIndex)

  return NSDecimalNumber(string: removed)
}
```

If your input number is a single digit, it would return NaN.

You could replace it to NSDecimalNumber.zero if you need.

It may works like delete button on calcultor.

---

It's not tested much.

If someone found another NaN case, please report by reply.